# To show that the quotient norm is the minimal norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Z$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$. To show that the quotient norm on the vector space $X/Z$ is the minimal norm such that if $Y$ is a normed space, $T \in B(X,Y)$ and $Z \subset \ker T$ then the norm of the induced operator $T_0: X/Z \to Y$ is at most $||T||$.

If $Z$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$ , then the quantity
$||x + Z|| := \inf_{y \in Z} ||x − y||$ is a norm on $X/Z$, called the **quotient norm**.

I am stuck with the problem. Hints required. Thank You.

Comment: You didn't define the inequality you want to prove, nor the norms for operators.

Comment: You'll wanna show that any norm on $X/Z$ with the expressed properties will be greater than or equal to the quotient norm